# .rodata section breaks after moving an object out of the function scope

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, sections, objcopy

I'm building a simple payload to [execute](https://fredericb.info/2021/02/amlogic-usbdl-unsigned-code-loader-for-amlogic-bootrom.html) on an ARM64 system that will print a "Hello, world!" string over UART.

hello-world-payload.c:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t u32;

int _start() {  
    const char* txt = "Hello, world!\n";
    volatile u32* uart_wfifo = (volatile u32*)0xc81004c0;
    volatile u32* uart_status = (volatile u32*)0xc81004cc;
    
    u32 i = 0;
    char c = txt[0];
    while (c) {
        // wait for UART availability
        do {} while (! (*uart_status & (1 << 22)) );
        // print 1 character
        *uart_wfifo = (0x000000ff & c);
        c = txt[++i];
    }
    
    while (1) {} // wait for watchdog
}
```

Makefile:

```
CROSS_COMPILE ?= aarch64-linux-gnu-
CC      = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
OBJCOPY = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy

AFLAGS  = -nostdlib
CFLAGS  = -O0 -nostdlib
LDFLAGS = -Wl,--build-id=none

all: hello-world-payload.bin

%.elf: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.bin: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -S -g --strip-unneeded \
        -j .text \
        -j .rodata \
        $< $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm hello-world-payload.bin
```

For cross compiler I use the gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf (AArch64 ELF bare-metal target) toolchain from ARM Developer.
With code above I get a 159 bytes binary that works just fine.

Once I move the `txt` out of the function scope this way:

```c
typedef uint32_t u32;
const char* txt = "Hello, world!\n";
int _start() {
```

, the payload doesn't run anymore. After loading the payload binary into Ghidra I notice that the code tries to access `txt` at `DAT_000100a0` while in fact it's stored at 0x90.

[image: Ghidra decompiler listing]

Since `txt` is `const` and is already initialized it should belong to the `.rodata` section which I confirmed by inspecting the assembly output of `${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -O0 -nostdlib -Wl,--build-id=none -o hello-world-payload.s hello-world-payload.c -S`, here's an excerpt from it:

```
    .arch armv8-a
    .file   "hello-world-payload.c"
    .text
    .global txt
    .section    .rodata
    .align  3
.LC0:
    .string "Hello, world!\n"
    .data
    .align  3
    .type   txt, %object
    .size   txt, 8
```

I made sure I didn't forget to include `.rodata` in Makefile:

```
%.bin: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -S -g --strip-unneeded \
        -j .text \
        -j .rodata \
        $< $@
```

The environment this binary runs in puts some constraints such as the max payload size (approx 29000 bytes in my case) and as far as I understood the binary must begin with the `.text` section so my goal is to keep the payload size as small as possible but I want to access various objects from different functions.

I inspected the `${CROSS_COMPILE}readelf -S` output for hello-world-payload.o (`${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -O0 -nostdlib -Wl,--build-id=none -o hello-world-payload.o hello-world-payload.c`):

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000     0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000400000  00010000     0000000000000090  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000400090  00010090     000000000000000f  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS         00000000004100a0  000100a0     0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [ 4] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000100a8     000000000000005d  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [ 5] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00010108     00000000000001e0  0000000000000018           6     9     8
  [ 6] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  000102e8     000000000000006f  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [ 7] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00010357     0000000000000038  0000000000000000
```

I see there's a `.data` section so I tried to add it to the `objcopy` command in my Makefile:

```
%.bin: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary -S -g --strip-unneeded \
        -j .text \
        -j .rodata \
        -j .data \
        $< $@
```

The binary size grows to whopping 65704 bytes but even with the `.data` section Ghidra shows the same `DAT_000100a0` reference with nothing like the `"Hello, world!\n" string at that position:

[image: DAT_000100a0 offset in broken binary with .data section added]

The actual string is at 0x90 as it was before adding the `.data` section.

It is clear to me that the compiler messes up addresses of `.rodata` section where the string resides but I don't know how to fix it. Adding `.data` section didn't help.

Comment: If you are compiling and linking on ARM there most probably is a linker script (normally as part of your toolchain) that tells where things need to go in the final binary. NOR flash can be used an addressable ROM for execution but being read only requires the data section to be copied into RAM. You are using _start as an entrypoint and not main. This may mean that some of the pre-execution initialization (like copying the data section) is not happening.

Comment: @doron I don't understand why you mentioned NOR flash because in order to run the payload on HW I have to exploit the BootROM and overwrite a part of its SRAM with the contents of payload file then jump to the entry point which should be `_start` at 0xD9000000. I think by the time the CPU is jumping to `_start` the program should be already fully copied into RAM by exploit. I need some time to understand the linker script used by my cross-compiler but I found out that .elf file is actually fine and it looks ok in ghidra, the objdump seems to damage the binary.

Comment: `typedef uint32_t u32;` Please don't write crap like that - use the standard names even if you find them cumbersome.

Comment: @Lundin I took this type definition from the Linux kernel source code and I will keep using what you just called "crap", thanks.

Comment: @kupper.m Please don't make the mistake of confusing the Linux kernel for some sort of canonical resource for how to write C. It's actually quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly with microcontrollers, the content of the `.data` section needs to be initialized by the start-up code from a section in non-volatile memory of the same size. Apparently your start-up code does not fulfill this requirement to run a C application.

In contrast to your belief, `txt` is an separate non-constant variable, because it is a modifiable pointer to the constant text. Your C code specifies to initialize this global variable with the address of the unnamed string. But no code does this.

You can make the global pointer variable constant, if you change your code to:

```c
const char * const txt = "Hello, world!\n";
```

Now `txt` is located in `.rodata`.

You can avoid the global pointer variable at all, if you change your code to:

```c
const char txt[] = "Hello, world!\n";
```

Now `txt` names the array of characters, which is located in `.rodata`.

---

In your first version of your program, `txt` was a dynamic variable on the stack. The code initialized it with the address of the unnamed string after entering the function `_start()`.

Comment: Regarding the .data section initialization, check out [How to perform initialization of static storage variables in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/287398)

Comment: My issue with proper start-up code is that I have to exploit a CVE-2021-0467 in order to run my own payloads. The BootROM of the s905x CPU already performs start-up routines on its own and then I exploit its USB stack to push a payload to CPU SRAM (that I think is r/w/x) and jump to it. So by the time my code is executed the minimal HW is already initialized, and I'm afraid that nested start-up code might mess up everything. I think out of all setup routines I just need to properly initialize sections. I will look into how the [picolibc](https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc) project does that.

Comment: I know this is just completely wrong but I'm wondering if it's possible to compile a binary with pre-initialized sections that I could push and simply jump to.

Comment: @kupper.m Please post a new question for this issue, this is not a forum. ;-) Short hint: yes. -- What you want is often possible with PCs that load programs into RAM to run them. Their `.data` section does not need to be copied (beside the loading action), because it is loaded in RAM. For the linker it does not matter whether the target memory part is read-only or not, it only looks at addresses. BTW, please be aware that the `.bss` section needs to be zeroed, too. Startup code has its purpose. In any case, you can provide it yourself.

Comment: @thebusybee I did more research before asking another question, and I *did* come up with a working solution. I wrote my own `ld` script where I defined the only memory region (SRAM) that is i/w/x, its base and size. My script lists `.data` section right after `.rodata`. The addresses aren't messed up anymore. I also implemented zeroing the whole .`bss` section at link time with `FILL(0)` statement. I ended up not needing any start-up code at all because HW is already started by the BootROM and `.data` and `.bss` don't need initializing because the resulting binary has everything initialized.